# How to merge dictonary values with the duplicates

Tags: python, django, dictionary

In Django, I have two annotated results from two different models and combined them using itertools which I got these results. Initially I was successfully manage to get all the duplicates and add their value using values().annotate(), my problem now is, from this list of dictionary, how can I achieve the result below. Basically I just want to get all the same setting_type and add their values.

Example: all 'bazel' should add the carat, quantity and salary except for the rate same with 'pave'. Thanks in advance.

```py
source_dict = [
{'setting_type': 'bazel', 'rate': 45, 'carat': 10.30, 'quantity': 10, 'salary': 450},
{'setting_type': 'pave', 'rate': 30, 'carat': 10.43, 'quantity': 10, 'salary': 300},
{'setting_type': 'center', 'rate': 10, 'carat': 3.35, 'quantity': 45, 'salary': 450},
{'setting_type': 'pave','rate': 30, 'carat': 4.10, 'quantity': 23, 'salary': 690},
{'setting_type': 'bazel', 'rate': 45, 'carat': 31.10, 'quantity': 50, 'salary': 2250}
]

desired_result = [
{'setting_type': 'bazel', 'rate': 45, 'carat': 41.40, 'quantity': 60, 'salary': 2700},
{'setting_type': 'pave', 'rate': 30, 'carat': 14.53, 'quantity': 33, 'salary': 990},
{'setting_type': 'center', 'rate': 10, 'carat': 3.35, 'quantity': 45, 'salary': 450}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict with values from `setting_type` as keys, and add all results based on whether it already appears in this dict.

```py
source_dict = [
{'setting_type': 'bazel', 'rate': 45, 'carat': 10.30, 'quantity': 10, 'salary': 450},
{'setting_type': 'pave', 'rate': 30, 'carat': 10.43, 'quantity': 10, 'salary': 300},
{'setting_type': 'center', 'rate': 10, 'carat': 3.35, 'quantity': 45, 'salary': 450},
{'setting_type': 'pave','rate': 30, 'carat': 4.10, 'quantity': 23, 'salary': 690},
{'setting_type': 'bazel', 'rate': 45, 'carat': 31.10, 'quantity': 50, 'salary': 2250}
]

result_dict = {}
for item in source_dict:
    st_key = item['setting_type']
    # check if 'setting_type' already exists in result_dict:
    if st_key not in result_dict:
        result_dict[st_key] = {}
    # add values
    for key, value in item.items():
        if key != 'setting_type':
            if key not in result_dict[st_key]:
                result_dict[st_key][key] = 0
            result_dict[st_key][key] += value
# reformat result_dict to list
results = []
for key, value in result_dict.items():
    value.update({'setting_type': key})
    results.append(value)
print(results)
# [
# {'setting_type': 'bazel', 'rate': 45, 'carat': 41.40, 'quantity': 60, 'salary': 2700},
# {'setting_type': 'pave', 'rate': 30, 'carat': 14.53, 'quantity': 33, 'salary': 990},
# {'setting_type': 'center', 'rate': 10, 'carat': 3.35, 'quantity': 45, 'salary': 450}
# ]
```

Comment: I have a question, how can exclude the rate from adding it's value? The way it works it should be rate*quantity=salary so rate should be the same. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: @Bewa to exclude other keys, edit this line: `if key != 'setting_type':` to `if key not in ['rate', 'setting_type']:`